# Bounding the difference between two points of the logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, probability-theory, logarithms, asymptotics

Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers.
Is it possible to obtain an asymptotic upper bound on the following difference:
$$
\log(n) - \log(n-k)
$$
Looking at the output of WolframAlpha it seems that, if $k ≤ n^{\epsilon}$, for $\epsilon<1/2$, then it holds (for sufficiently large $n$) that
$$
\log(n) - \log(n-k) \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.  \quad (1)
$$

I have been trying to apply various logarithmic identities, but I could not come up with a proof. For now I'm just looking at the case $k = n^{1/4}$. Can you help me finding a proof for (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\log(n)-\log(n-k)&=\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n-k}\right)\\&\lt\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{1-\varepsilon}-1}\right)\\&\lt\frac{1}{n^{1-\varepsilon}-1}\\&\lt\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-1}\\&\lt\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\end{align}$$

Feel free to ask if any of the steps were unclear. We actually get the stronger inequalities as shown above. $0\lt\varepsilon\lt\frac{1}{2}$ is essential, as is $k\le n^{\varepsilon}$ and $n\gt1$. However, "sufficiently large $n$" is really just for any $n\gt1$ - **this is not asymptotic, but generally true**.

The inequality is also remarkably tight for large $n$ and $\varepsilon\approx1/2$, $k\approx n^\varepsilon$.